# Object id after update command mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While inserting in mongodb by mongoskin i could get object id by following. Which is working absoultely well

```
     db.collection('test').insert({
     version: nc.version,
     }, function (err, result) {
 // This would give me objectID of nre
    console.log('creating new version ', result.ops[0]._id);
         }
   })
```

---

While update with {upsert:true} in collection i couldn't find anything

```
           db.collection('test').update({labId: lab_id},{$set:
            {
            version: nc.version,
        }},{upsert:true}, function (error, result) {

             if (error){
                 // If there is error then
                 console.log("Error occured while adding in system");
             }
            console.log('Result is  ', result);
         })
```

Result what is print is like this one. So i would like to know where i could find my objectid (i.e. _id which we get after object is added in mongodb)

```
 Result is  {
  result: { n: 1, nModified: 0, upserted: [ [Object] ], ok: 1 },
  connection: 
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     options: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        size: 5,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        socketTimeout: 30000,
        keepAlive: true,
        keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
        noDelay: true,
        ssl: false,
        checkServerIdentity: true,
        ca: null,
        cert: null,
        key: null,
        passPhrase: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false,
        reconnect: true,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        domainsEnabled: false,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        emitError: true,
        socketOptions: {},
        clientInfo: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        native_parser: true,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        bson: BSON {} },
     id: 0,
     logger: Logger { className: 'Connection' },
     bson: BSON {},
     tag: undefined,
     messageHandler: [Function],
     maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
     port: 27017,
     host: 'localhost',
     keepAlive: true,
     keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
     noDelay: true,
     connectionTimeout: 30000,
     socketTimeout: 30000,
     destroyed: false,
     domainSocket: false,
     singleBufferSerializtion: true,
     serializationFunction: 'toBinUnified',
     ca: null,
     cert: null,
     key: null,
     passphrase: null,
     ssl: false,
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
     checkServerIdentity: true,
     responseOptions: 
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     flushing: false,
     queue: [],
     connection: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 2134,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 3254,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     writeStream: null,
     hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c',
     workItems: [ [Object] ],
     buffer: null,
     sizeOfMessage: 0,
     bytesRead: 0,
     stubBuffer: null },
  message: 
   Response {
     parsed: true,
     index: 126,
     raw: <Buffer 7e 00 00 00 c0 90 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d ... >,
     data: <Buffer 7e 00 00 00 c0 90 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d ... >,
     bson: BSON {},
     opts: 
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     length: 126,
     requestId: 37056,
     responseTo: 3,
     responseFlags: 8,
     cursorId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
     startingFrom: 0,
     numberReturned: 1,
     documents: [ [Object] ],
     cursorNotFound: false,
     queryFailure: false,
     shardConfigStale: false,
     awaitCapable: true,
     promoteLongs: true,
     promoteValues: true,
     promoteBuffers: false,
     hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

`collection.update()` will only report the number of documents that were affected to its own callback.

To retrieve the documents while modifying, you can use `collection.findOneAndUpdate()` or `collection.findAndModify()`

**collection.findOneAndUpdate:**

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>
   }
)
```

Refrence : [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

With your Problem :

```
       db.test.findOneAndUpdate(
           {labId: lab_id},
           {$set:{version:nc.version},
           {
             upsert: true,
             returnNewDocument: true // use this key if wanted modified document
           }, 
           function (error, result) {

             if (error){
                 // If there is error then
                 console.log("Error occured while adding in system");
             }
            console.log('Result is  ', result);
         })
        )
```

**collection.findOneAndModify:**

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: <document>,
    sort: <document>,
    remove: <boolean>,
    update: <document>,
    new: <boolean>,
    fields: <document>,
    upsert: <boolean>,
    bypassDocumentValidation: <boolean>,
    writeConcern: <document>,
    collation: <document>
});
```

Reference : [findOneAndModify:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

***Note :*** Use findOneAndUpdate and findOneAndModify only if u want to update a single document because multi true is not available in them .

Comment: 1. I need to add document only through update.(upsert:true) to check if duplicates doesn;'t exist 2. Question was regarding objectID i.e. where did i get id_ in result after this one.

Comment: U will get _id in result variable and above code will work same as of update i have also given option upsert true

Comment: Above example will work for ur query as u r not using {multi:true}